# Unable to make a javascript get to a ruby on rails XML page

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, xml

I have an application running on Ruby on Rails that returns an XML page like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<list>
  <item title="Professor" href="437">name1</item>
  <item title="Professor" href="1">name2</item>
  <item title="Professor" href="2">name3</item>
  <item title="Professor" href="438">name4</item>
  <start>1</start>
  <end>4</end>
</list>
```

which I get by accessing

http://localhost:3001/people.xml

When, in the browser, I get this page everything is fine but if I use this following code in jquery

```
$.get('http://localhost:3001/people.xml', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

I get, in firebug, the following error:

XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{ca8a9975-1761-4999-a65a-fe7d0a810762} Line Number 1, Column 1:

What can it possibly be ?

Thanks!

Comment: That looks like a problem with Firebug and Firefox rather than your own code. Have you tried it in Chrome's developer tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the port where I was making the get request (3000) was different from the one who had the data (3001), thus receiving this error.

This happens because one is not able to make ajax get's to a website running in a different domain or port.

The solution passed by making the request in ajax to my own controller (in port 3000) and, in the controller, making the request to the port 3001 and then returning it back.

Keep in mind that in ajax you can only make requests to the **same domain,** in the **same port**!

Hope it helps you.